# Plot straight line of best fit on log-log plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Have some data that I've plotted on a log-log plot and now I want to fit a straight line through these points. I have tried various methods and can't get what I'm after. Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

x= np.linspace(1,100,10)
y = np.log10(x)+np.log10(np.random.uniform(0,10))
coefficients = np.polyfit(np.log10(x),np.log10(y),1)
polynomial=np.poly1d(coefficients)
y_fit = polynomial(y)
plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.plot(x,y_fit,'-')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
```

This gives me a ideal 'straight' line in log log offset by a random number to which I then fit a 1d poly. The output is:

[image]

So ignoring the offset, which I can deal with, it is not quite what I require as it has basically plotted a straight line between each point and then joined them up whereas I need a 'line of best fit' through the middle of them all so I can measure the gradient of it.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is

```
y_fit = polynomial(y)
```

You must plug in the `x` values, not `y`, to get `y_fit`.

Also, you fit `log10(y)` with `log10(x)`, so to evaluate the linear interpolator, you must plug in `log10(x)`, and the result will be the base-10 log of the `y` values.

Here's a modified version of your script, followed by the plot it generates.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random


x = np.linspace(1,100,10)
y = np.log10(x) + np.log10(np.random.uniform(0,10))

coefficients = np.polyfit(np.log10(x), np.log10(y), 1)
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)
log10_y_fit = polynomial(np.log10(x))  # <-- Changed

plt.plot(x, y, 'o-')
plt.plot(x, 10**log10_y_fit, '*-')     # <-- Changed
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
```

[image: plot]

Comment: This looks like exactly what i'm looking for except it doesn't work like this when I try it? This is what I have - [link](https://imgur.com/Oz28bSS) and this is the results - [link](https://imgur.com/d2AnDvr) . It looks very similar to yours or am I missing something obvious? Thanks.

Comment: In that code, you plot `10**np.log10(y_fit)`.  Don't take the `log10` of `y_fit`; just plot `10**y_fit`.

Comment: Hi, that still isn't quite outputting what you get - I just changed it so I didn't take the `log10` of `y_fit`, just `10**y_fit` instead - I get [link](https://imgur.com/JI1sOdf). Your answer makes good sense to me: fit a polynomial to the log10 values of x/y then fit that to log10x and plot it. I'm not so sure why you 10** it when you finally plot it though? And i'm also not sure why mine does not give the same output as yours!